# C++ Delete node of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I created Binary Search Tree with strings.
Each node contains the string and the frequency of the string.

So the problem gives me two strings. I have to replace `s1` with `s2`. If `s2` doesn't exist I create a new node with the frequency of `s1`. If `s2` exists I add the frequency of `s1` to the frequency of `s2`.
In the code below I skipped the replace part. I only delete `s1` and save its frequency.
It doesn't work though... It doesn't print anything...

```
struct node{
    string data;
    int freq;
    node *left, *right;
    node(string d, int f){
        data = d;
        freq = f;
        left = right = nullptr;
    }
};
class lexicon {
public:
    lexicon();
    ~lexicon();

    void insert(const string &s);
    int lookup(const string &s);
    int depth(const string &s);
    void replace(const string &s1, const string &s2);

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const lexicon &l);
private:
    node *root;
    static node *FindMin(node* r){
        if(r == nullptr)
            return nullptr;

        while(r->left != nullptr)
            r = r->left;

        return r;
        }
    static node *DeleteNode(node *r, string v){
        if(r == nullptr)
            return r;

        int state = v.compare(r->data);
        if(state > 0)
            r->right = DeleteNode(r->right, v);
        else if(state < 0)
            r->left = DeleteNode(r->left, v);
        else {
            //No child
            if(r->right == nullptr && r->left == nullptr){
                delete r;
                r = nullptr;
            }
            //One child
            else if(r->right == nullptr){
                node *temp = r;
                r = r->left;
                delete temp;
            }
            else if(r->left == nullptr){
                node *temp = r;
                r = r->right;
                delete temp;
            }
            //Two children
            else{
                node *temp = FindMin(r->right);
                r->data = temp->data;
                r->freq = temp->freq;
                r->right = DeleteNode(r->right,temp->data);
            }
            return r;

        }
    }
};

void lexicon::replace(const string &s1, const string &s2){
    root = DeleteNode(root, s1);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you inspect your code stepping through line by line using the debugger, that should give you a grasp what's going wrong with it.

Comment: I am using codeblocks but I have no idea how to set up and use a debugger.(I used a debugger when I was taking cs50 course at git hub but even though I tried to use dubugger on codeblocks I didnt find out how to ...)

Comment: _"I am using codeblocks but I have no idea how to set up and use a debugger."_ Easy to find material: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jab1qj_QR8s http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: I think that's the video I used the last time I tried. I guess I should try again. Thanks

Comment: For me it's easier to study the documentation than watchng videos. You probably should consider to go with the latter link.

Comment: tbh the same applies to me but I didnt notice the 2nd link(lol), thanks!

Comment: @stylch You really should write the function to delete a node from a binary tree, i.e. this function: `DeleteNode(node *r)` should have been written first.  The other criteria about strings -- that should have been a separate function altogether, where all it does is pinpoint the node, then your code just calls `DeleteNode` using that node pointer.  Deleting a node from a binary tree is one of the basic functionalities it should support.